# Java CLI arguments are ignored when running the program when windows start

Tags: java, command-line-interface, startupscript

I created a Java program that I want to automatically run when I turn on my PC, so I made the following `run.bat` and put it in Window's Startup folder:

```
start javaw -jar "Program.jar" "some default arg"
```

When I double click it myself, everything works. 
But after I restart my PC, I always get an `ArrayIndexOutBoundsException` for the line that accesses `args[0]`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: *I always get an ArrayIndexOutBoundsException* Out of interest, how do you know that? javaw.exe doesn't normally show a window, still less so when it's 'scheduled'

Comment: I have a GUI global exception handler which which uses common lang's `ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(Throwable)`.

Comment: The first argument to start seems to be for a "title" so try `start "" javaw -jar "Program.jar" "some default arg"` (double quotes with no content)

Comment: @g00se I still get the exact same error.

Comment: Hmm. Try a Windows shortcut instead of the batch file

Comment: But I need CLI arguments..? @g00se

Comment: Shortcuts can take arguments